# stopwatch in javascript using new Date object

Tags: javascript

In script below i try to make some kind of stopwatch:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script>
     var t; var time; var timetoRun=180000;// 3 min

     function Timer()
     {
      stoper = (this.startTime+ this.timetoRun)-new Date().getTime();
      x = parseInt(stoper / 1000);
      s = x % 60;
      x = parseInt(x/60);
      m = x % 60;
      if (s<10) s='0'+ s;document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=m+':'+s; 
      this.t=setTimeout(function(){Timer()},500);
     }

    function myStopFunction(){clearTimeout(t);}
    function init(){this.startTime = new Date().getTime();}
   </script>
  </head>

   <body onload="init()">
     <div id="txt"></div>
     <button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop time</button>
     <button onclick="Timer()">Start time</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

**The problem is** : when i stop time at `2:28` and start it again after 5 sec. value jump at once to `2:23` . What i want to achieve is: stop time at (for example) `2:31` and run it again from `2:31`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the solution you are looking for

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script>
     var t; 
     var time; 
     var timetoRun=180000;// 3 min
     var lastTime = -1;

    function StartTimer() {
        this.startTime = new Date().getTime();
        this.lastTime = lastTime < 0 ? this.timetoRun : this.lastTime;
        this.timetoRun = this.lastTime;
        Timer();
    };

     function Timer() {
      var difference = (this.startTime - new Date().getTime());
      console.log(difference / 1000);
      this.lastTime = this.timetoRun + difference;
      x = parseInt(this.lastTime / 1000);
      s = x % 60;
      x = parseInt(x/60);
      m = x % 60;
      if (s<10) s='0'+ s;

      document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=m+':'+s; 

      this.t=setTimeout(function(){
        Timer();
        },500);
     }

    function myStopFunction() {
      clearTimeout(t);
    };

   </script>

  </head>

   <body>
     <div id="txt"></div>
     <button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop time</button>
     <button onclick="StartTimer()">Start time</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

or you can try it here

http://plnkr.co/edit/ySOGRCvnPILNTinCriCL?p=preview

Comment: ,Fabrizio thx for fast help, I choose this answer becouse it keeps in usage new date object

Comment: @maciekm just for my curiosity, why do you need to use a Date Object?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan This is part of my hobby project, online board game, where i need to keep time accuracy

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan and i need to store time in milsec. o n server side

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify a lot your code so to avoid the use of a `Date` object.

Furthermore you have forgot some `var` keyword and a condition to stop your timer when the time has run out. I've also inserted a `resetTimer` method so if you need to restart the timer twice or more, it will be set to `180` seconds again

Example codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Duier

**Code**

```
      var 
         // seconds
         timetoRun,             
         // cache a reference to the DOM element in which you update the timer
         timeElement, 
         // your interval
         intv;

      function Timer() {
          var ss = timetoRun % 60;
          var mm = (timetoRun / 60) | 0;  // Math.floor

          if (ss < 10) ss = '0' + ss;
          timeElement.innerHTML = [mm,ss].join(":"); 

          if (timetoRun-- > 0) {
              intv = setTimeout(Timer, 1000);
          }
          else {
              myStopFunction();
              resetTimer();
          }
      };

      function myStopFunction() {  clearInterval(intv); };

      function resetTimer() {
         timetoRun = 180  //second;
      };

      function init() { 
         resetTimer(); 
         timeElement = document.getElementById('txt');
      };
```

Comment: +1 very nice clean script, but i have to keep in usage date object

Answer (score 0):

I think you have really over complicated things here the simpler way would be to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/4Ey9Z/2/

```
 var timetoRun=180000; var timer, elem = document.getElementById('txt');

    function startTime(){
        timer= setInterval(function(){CountDown()},1000);
        }
    function stopTime(){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    function CountDown(){
         var seconds = parseInt((timetoRun/1000)%60,0)
                , minutes = parseInt((timetoRun/(1000*60))%60,0);
               timetoRun = timetoRun - 1000;
        elem.innerHTML=minutes+':'+seconds;
       if((seconds===0)&&(minutes ===0)){
            stopTime();
}

    }
```

Comment: Two major problems: the counter never stops and you access the dom element everytime you call the `CountDown` function. furthermore `parseInt` requires a base as a second parameter

Comment: You are correct it was a quick mock up to show you dont need to use date, in real life I would not use global varibles or click functions either :) But I have update the answer with your points :)