# When i lock the phone the timer is stopping

Tags: javascript

I have a timer in javascript and when i lock the phone the timer still count few minutes and after that is stopping. If i unlock the phone the timer start to count. There is any way that the timer still count whent the mobile phone screen is off?

```
    <script>
    var seconds=0;
    function pad(val) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; } 
     if(sessionStorage.getItem("self.totalSeconds") != null ){

            $("#min").text(pad(Math.floor(sessionStorage.getItem("self.totalSeconds") / 60 % 60)));
      $("#sec").text(pad(parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("self.totalSeconds") % 60)));
            seconds=parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("self.totalSeconds"));
          }else{
            $("#min").text("00");
            $("#sec").text("00");
          }
    var Clock = {
      totalSeconds: seconds,
      start: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.interval = setInterval(function () {

          if(sessionStorage.getItem("self.totalSeconds") == null ){
            self.totalSeconds += 1;
          }else{
            self.totalSeconds=parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("self.totalSeconds"));
            self.totalSeconds += 1;
          }
          sessionStorage.setItem("self.totalSeconds", self.totalSeconds);

          $("#min").text(pad(Math.floor(sessionStorage.getItem("self.totalSeconds") / 60 % 60)));
          $("#sec").text(pad(parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("self.totalSeconds") % 60)));

        }, 1000);

      },

      pause: function () {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        delete this.interval;
      },
    };

    Clock.start();
    $('#pauseButton').click(function () {
     $("#errorMessage").text("");
     $("#errorMessage").hide();
     var totalSecondstobeexported = Clock.totalSeconds;
});
  </script>
```

Comment: Any example code of what you are trying to archive by this?

Comment: Let me guess you are using setTimeout or setInterval? Some basic code would help.

Comment: Is this web app running in browser on the phone? Or phone application written in JavaScript?

Comment: It's running in the browser on the phone.

Comment: Since you added code, setTimout/setInterval is not accurate for calculating elapsed time. It will drift. Look at something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782369/stopwatch-in-javascript-using-new-date-object where they subtract two date objects

Comment: You should calculate time diff by `Date.now() - lastTimeVar` instead of relying on `setInterval( , 1000)`

Comment: Code in a web page does not continue running while the browser is not in active use with that page open; so the counter can't keep ticking while the phone is locked.  You could put the time when the counter begins in localStorage, and have the counter work based on the elapsed time instead of an interval -- that would get the correct time to display even if the page is closed in the interim, but wouldn't allow you to (for example) set an alarm to go off while the page isn't open, if that sort of thing is your goal.